# Did [name-resolution] fail?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I've discovered today tag [name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-resolution) and think that it is completely useless and should be burinated.

Some statistics:

- 0 followers
- 51 questions

It is used in (at least) three cases:

1. Network name resolution (use [network-name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-name-resolution) or something similar instead)
2. Name resolution in code (remove, language tag is enough)
3. Name resolution in IDE (remove, IDE tag is enough)

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the burnination. The tag needs a [tag-disambiguation](/questions/tagged/tag-disambiguation) and a [rename-request](/questions/tagged/rename-request) instead. A tag being "useless" isn't a strong and a valid argument for burnination. There are [4 questions which are to be answered instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). Going one by one:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  Partial No. The tag is ambiguous, but if we consider the other tags in the question then it is quite clear that the tag describes the contents of the question. If it is tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), or any other programming language, then it is very clear that the question is about the [resolution of the tokens within program expressions to the intended program components.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)) If it has a networking tag then it is clear that the question is related to [domain name resolutions or the DNS service.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Yes. The concept is completely on-topic for the site. Both [variable name resolutions and domain name resolutions are completely on-topic on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In fact name resolution in C++ is something which we need. Even though the [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) seems more like a Server Fault or a Super User concept, there are lots of [programming questions related to the domain name resolution system which are on topic for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dns/info)
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Yes. Adding the [name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-resolution) to the post along with the language tags makes it clear that the question is related to resolving either token names (both static name resolution and dynamic name resolution). It also helps to filter those questions that are related to name resolutions (amongst similar concepts like scoping, namespaces, etc). Similarly the [name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-resolution) along with other networking related tags indicate that the programming question involved is about the DNS. Therefore the tag certainly isn't [superfluous on the vast majority of questions where it is used, then it should go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and does add meaningful information to the post.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No. This is the one question which has been answered in the original post. Apart from the two ambiguities (token resolution and domain name resolution), there are multiple other meanings which it can have in the common context. The 0 watchers of the post does not help us as well.

The process for [burninating tags clearly states that a tag must fail all the tests for a tag to be burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/4099593). Here it fails 2 of the 4.

Now for the disambiguation:

- Half the questions [are related to the domain name resolution service.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bname-resolution%5D%20dns&mixed=0) These should be re-tagged as [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) instead.
- Most of the remaining half are related to the token name resolution. If most of the questions were related to this, the it could have remained as it is, and we could have retagged the new wrongly tagged questions on the go. However, it seems like most of the users are not using the tag properly. Therefore we can rename it as [token-name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token-name-resolution) (other suggestions are welcome).
- The tag needs to be removed from the other questions (I can just see one or two others).
- The tag wiki page of both [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) and [token-name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/token-name-resolution) should be updated to mention what its purpose is and about the other tag.

The tag [name-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/name-resolution) is infact a good tag and deserved to be kept as such for token name resolutions. But given that there's a similarly named service, and that the usage is almost 50-50, we will have to go for a disambiguation here. (if less than 20% of the posts were wrongly tagged, then we could have let it remain)

Comment: It is worth noting that "name resolution" is not really a common C++ term as far as I'm aware. Instead, ["name lookup"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) and then potentially ["overload resolution"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) are performed to match a name to some declared entity. But I'd say it's a valid way to express the intent nonetheless.