# Rename [meetup] to [meetup-api]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

The [meetup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meetup) excerpt is fairly clear

> Meetup is an online social networking portal that facilitates offline group meetings in various localities around the world.

But I've seen [at least one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439212/software-licenses-to-be-raffled-at-meetups) misuse it for general meetups.

A rename to [meetup-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meetup-api) would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having to retag *one* questions is not an issue. Having to retag a handful of questions isn't an issue. I went through all the questions, the other wrongly tagged ones were:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668241/how-to-make-a-fun-effective-programming-meetup-that-benefits-both-beginners-and

So the tag is being used correctly, in 96.875% of the times. Renaming a tag would make sense when the tag is being wrongly used *frequently*, and here it isn't (See [the [fix] case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371686/4099593)) To quantize it to a number, we can say that if a tag is mistagged 20% of the times, then a rename would help. (See the [[name-resolution] case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372448/4099593), where it was 50-50)

Another point which Kevin brought up this morning, [while we were discussing the rename of the [processing] tag:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286694/rename-processing-to-processing-language-or-similar/288691?noredirect=1#comment632096_288691)

> I'd rather make it as easy as possible for legitimate Processing users to find the tag.

Putting that here, it would be easier for the legitimate users of the Meetup API to find it more easily.

Therefore I feel that a rename of the tag isn't necessary here.